# PHP7 is not installed correctly on apache2?

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2

I installed phpmyadmin in my raspberry pi. Everything was okay, I didn't get any error during the installation.

But when I go to 192.168.1.5/phpmyadmin I see the following page:

[image]

Could it be that I didn't install correctly php for Apache? But I already installed it with `sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0`!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt update   //update
sudo apt install apache2  //you done this 

sudo apt install mysql-server  //install mysql server
```

then

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql    //install php 

sudo systemctl restart apache2   //restart apache2 

sudo apt install php-cli   //install php-cli 



sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php



<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

ctrl+x and Y

http://your_server_ip/info.php   //its will sow information about php